# Spring MVC Handler Interceptor does not run

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have following interceptor class :

```
package cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class RestAuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

        System.out.println("fuu");
        response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED );
        return false;
    }
}
```

I configured it inside my spring-webmvc.xml as following :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
     <mvc:interceptor>
       <mvc:mapping path="/rest/api/01/status" />
       <bean class="cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors.RestAuthorizationInterceptor" />
     </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>     

</beans>
```

However when I go to `http://localhost:8080/myserver/rest/api/01/status`, I get regular answer with status code 200 (same as before I added interceptor). Also, message "fuu" is not printed (so the preHandle method is not called).

Any ideas? I started to do it with this example : http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-mvc-handler-interceptor/, but all other examples look the same, I cant find where I go wrong.

I am using Spring `3.2.4.RELEASE`

---

Important edit, it works with this :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
 <mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
   <bean class="cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors.RestAuthorizationInterceptor" />
 </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

So the question is, what is wrong with my path?

Comment: any log ? errors ? As its prehandle, the response will be overridden by your normal controller method won't it - the prehandle is normally for dealing with the request.

Comment: Nothing happens, no errors, the method is not called (how I said, no output for System.out.println("fuu") appears). Also when you return false on preHandle, it should intercept controller method...

Comment: Does the interceptor work when you remove the mapping?

Comment: @geoand - SAXError appears : `Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":mapping}' is expected.`

Comment: Try this:  <mvc:interceptors>
       <bean class="cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors.RestAuthorizationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

Comment: @geoand - good point, I edited my question with result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found solution, because my path is defined with following :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this is how my controller looks like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/01/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ServerStatusJSON getStatus(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The working configuration for this address : `http://localhost:8080/myserver/rest/api/01/status` is as following :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
 <mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/api/01/status" />
   <bean class="cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors.RestAuthorizationInterceptor" />
 </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

PS : My thanks to geoand, he pushed me to the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the value of `mvc:mapping`. My working configuration is:

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="cn.mmd.micro.common.TokenInterceptor">
            <property name="excludeUrls">
                <list>
                    <value>/app/token</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing additional explanation as to why this method worked for libik. As he has mentioned his controller looks like -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/01/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ServerStatusJSON getStatus(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And also remember interceptors are at `HandlerMapping` level. In this case it would be `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` (Spring 3.1+ with `mvc:annotation-driven`) or `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`. and the mapping here would be for
`/api/01/status` which is precisely what he has done.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
 <mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/api/01/status" />
   <bean class="cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors.RestAuthorizationInterceptor" />
 </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

If you want it to be applied for all patterns you can simply do `<mvc:mapping path="/**"/>` - this will match all URLs (including subpaths) or you can simply invoke interceptors for all HandlerMappings -

```
<mvc:interceptors> 
<bean class="cz.coffeeexperts.feedback.server.web.interceptors.RestAuthorizationInterc‌​eptor" /> 
</mvc:interceptors>
```