# Why Spring interceptor is bypassed for bad URLs?

Tags: spring-mvc

My web application runs on Spring (MVC) 4.2.9.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.1.3.Final, and Spring Data 1.8.2.RELEASE.

I have the following interceptor in the Spring context.

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"> 
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="interceptors"> 
        <list>
                ...
            <ref local="myIntercepter" /> 
            ... 
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

The interceptor "myIntercepter" is able to intercept valid URLs such as

```
http://localhost/s?mid=cflbv1zipb8d7&lang=en_US
```

However, for the following invalid URL (has a question mark in the end)

```
http://localhost/s?mid=cflbv1zipb8d7&lang=en_US?
```

The interceptor does not get called. I am not sure why this behavior happens. I have to make sure all web traffic to go through the interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure a piece of code gets executed for every web request coming in, I'd recommend using a Filter instead of a HandlerInterceptor.  Spring MVC might be trying to parse the querystring or something to that effect prior to the interceptor being called, or it can't find a handler due to the invalid url.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! In the interceptor, I set up the environment for each web request. However, such setup for images, css files, etc. does not make sense because each image, etc. request goes through filters (but not through interceptors if you set up Spring correctly).

Comment: With the invalid url, does your controller method ever get called?

Comment: If it doesn't, I'm guessing that's why your HandlerInterceptor isn't being called, Since no handler has been found to handle your request.  Keep in mind you can exclude images, css, and whatever you want in Filters by url paths or extensions.

Comment: You are right. My controller never gets called because it is called after interceptor. I understand that I could examine URLs in filters, but I am reluncant to use such custom code. Does Spring come with any configs for Filters? Upvoted all your responses. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Np.  I don't believe that Spring has anything out of the box for that. Usually what I'll do is just throw up an error page or something if the url is invalid -- or sometimes sanitize it if I can with a filter.  I'd just look at whatever response code you're getting (I'm guessing 404 because it's probably trying to consider the first querystring separator as part of the requested resource, and the second separator as the querystring separator). (continued next comment)

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to do this at a pretty low level stage in the request pipeline (such as filter) because by the time your request reaches a HandlerInterceptor, Spring has already chosen a controller to process your request.  It just can't do that if the URL is invalid.  In fact, your controller is passed into your HandlerInterceptor as an argument in preHandle(), postHandle(), and afterCompletion().

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293368/spring-mvc-handler-interceptor-does-not-run   --- That might be a workaround you can use.  Take a look at Aniket's response (at the very bottom)